# Como obtener el valor de un input radio con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero que cuanto el usuario le de click a un input radio, su valor se almacene en un input text, y cuando seleccione otro input radio, que el input text se actualice con el valor del input text que se actualice.

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio")
let campo_checkButton = document.querySelector(".campo_checkButton")

for(let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
radio[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

campo_checkButton = radio[i].value

  })
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="1">1<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="2">2<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="3">3<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="4">4<label>

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" class="campo_checkButton" value="Vacio">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tiene la referencia del elemento en su variable `campo_checkButton` , lo que haría falta es setear el valor que obtiene del `radio`, y esto se hace con el atributo [.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value) , es decir `campo_checkButton.value = radio[i].value`

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio")
let campo_checkButton = document.querySelector(".campo_checkButton")

for(let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
 radio[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
  campo_checkButton.value = radio[i].value
 })
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="1">1<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="2">2<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="3">3<label>
<label><input type="radio" name="sexo" class="radio" value="4">4<label>

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" class="campo_checkButton" value="Vacio">
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta :D